# Send chained select values in email

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a chained select dropdown list and I want the values witch are chosen to be exported to my main app, through email or somehow. I'm not sure what is the best solution. Here is the code example

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.chained.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"></script>

<select id="year" name="year">
  <option value= "">Step 1 - Select Year</option>
  <option value="1990">1990</option>
  <option value="1991">1991</option>
  <option value="1992">1992</option>
</select>

<select id="model" name="model">
  <option value="">Step 2 - Select Model</option>
  <option value="80" class="1990 1991 1992">80</option>
</select>

<select id="engine" name="engine">
  <option value="">Step 3 - Select Engine</option>
  <option value="v10" class="80">v10</option>
</select>


 <input id="button1" type="button" value="send!" />

<script src="jquery.chained.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#model").chained("#year")
  $("#engine").chained("#model")
  $(document).ready(function (){ 
  $('#button1').click(function (){ 
  alert($(':selected').text());
</script>
```

The alert is showing the selected options, but i need to export that text somehow so i can send it like a newsletter to my app.
If anyone can tell me what is the best way to do that i will be grateful and sorry if i didn't explain it good or if you can't understand what i mean.

Comment: Could you give a more meaningful title to the question?

Comment: The title should have the main information of your problem....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (the JavaScript code using jQuery), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.cDropdown = function(x) {

    return this.each(function() {

      var wrapper = $(this);
      var xx = $.extend({
        obj: "",
      }, x || {});

      var lastCreated;

      function initialized() {
        var returnedData
        $.grep(xx.obj, function(element, index) {
          $.each(element, function(e, i) {
            if (hasValue(i, "Primary", true)) {
              returnedData = hasValue(i, "Primary", true);
              return false;
            }
          })
        });

        initFirst(returnedData);
        creator(xx.obj, returnedData)
        clicker(returnedData);
        runOrder(returnedData["Id"]);
      }

      function clicker(obj) {
        var selector = obj["Id"] != null ? "#" + obj["Id"] : obj["Name"] != null ? "[Name=\"" + obj["Name"] + "\"]" : ""
        $('body').on('change', selector, function() {
          var se = $(selector).find('option[value="CPreQVa"]');
          if (se.val() != $(this).find('option:selected').val()) {
            var target = $(this).attr("class").split("cTrig_")[1];
            var v = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
            var d;
            if ($('#' + target).is('[class*="cTrig_"]')) {
              hideFollow($('#' + target))
            }
            $.each(xx.obj[0], function(i, o) {
              if (hasValue(o, "Id", target) != null) {
                d = hasValue(o, "Id", target);
                return false;
              }
            });
            $('#' + target).find('option').remove();
            if (d != null) {
              $.each(d["option"], function(i, o) {
                var ot = "" + o["trigger"];

                if (ot.indexOf(",") != -1) {
                  var arrot = ot.split(',');
                  $.each(arrot, function(ii, oo) {
                    if (v == oo || o["preSelect"] == true) {
                      $('#' + target).append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", o["val"])
                        .text(o["text"]));
                      return false;
                    }
                  })
                } else {
                  if (v == o["trigger"] || o["preSelect"] == true) {
                    $('#' + target).append($("<option></option>")
                      .attr("value", o["val"])
                      .text(o["text"]));
                  }
                }
              })

              if (d["Sort"] != null && d["Sort"] === true) {
                var options = $('#' + target).find("option");
                var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {
                  return {
                    t: $(o).text(),
                    v: o.value
                  };
                }).get();
                arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
                  return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
                });
                options.each(function(i, o) {
                  o.value = arr[i].v;
                  $(o).text(arr[i].t);
                });
              }
              var t;
              $.each(d["option"], function(i, o) {
                t = hasValue(o, "preSelect", true)
                return false;
              })
              if (t != null) {

                $('#' + target).find('option[value="CPreQVa"]').prependTo($('#' + target)).attr("selected", true)
              }

              $('#' + target).show();

              var q;
              $.each(xx.obj[0], function(i, o) {
                if (hasValue(o, "Id", obj["Child"])) {
                  q = hasValue(o, "Id", obj["Child"]);
                  return false;
                }
              })
              if (q != null) {
                if (q["Child"] != null) {
                  clicker(q);
                }
              }
            }

          } else {
            var target = $(this).attr("class").split("cTrig_")[1]
            if ($('#' + target).is('[class*="cTrig_"]')) {
              hideFollow($('#' + target))
            }
            $('#' + target).hide();
          }



        })
      };

      function hideFollow(obj) {
        var target = $(obj).attr("class").split("cTrig_")[1]
        if ($('#' + target).is('[class*="cTrig_"]')) {
          hideFollow($('#' + target))
        }
        $('#' + target).hide();
      };

      function initFirst(obj) {
        if (obj["Id"] != null)
          wrapper.attr("Id", obj["Id"])
        if (obj["Name"] != null)
          wrapper.attr("Name", obj["Name"])
        if (obj["Class"] != null)
          wrapper.addClass(obj["Class"] + " cTrig_" + obj["Child"])
        $.each(obj["option"], function(e, i) {
          wrapper.append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value", i["val"])
            .text(i["text"]));
        })
        if (obj["Required"] != null)
          wrapper.prop('required', true);
        if (obj["Sort"] != null && obj["Sort"] === true) {
          var options = wrapper.find("option");
          var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {
            return {
              t: $(o).text(),
              v: o.value
            };
          }).get();
          arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
            return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
          });
          options.each(function(i, o) {
            o.value = arr[i].v;
            $(o).text(arr[i].t);
          });
        }
        var t;
        $.each(obj["option"], function(i, o) {
          t = hasValue(o, "preSelect", true)
          return false;
        })
        if (t != null) {
          //$('#MyNiceList option[value="my_option_2"]').insertBefore('#MyNiceList option[value="my_option_1"]');
          wrapper.find('option[value="CPreQVa"]').prependTo(wrapper).attr("selected", true)
        }
      };

      function hasValue(o, key, value) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(key) && o[key] === value)
          return o;
      };

      function creator(ob, fo) {
        $.each(ob[0], function(i, o) {
          if (o["Id"] != fo["Id"]) {
            var sel = $('<select>')
            if (o["Id"] != null)
              sel.attr("Id", o["Id"])
            if (o["Name"] != null)
              sel.attr("Name", o["Name"])
            if (o["Class"] != null)
              sel.addClass(o["Class"])
            if (o["Required"] != null)
              sel.prop('required', true);
            if (o["Child"] != null)
              sel.addClass("cTrig_" + o["Child"])
            //if (lastCreated == null) {
            //    sel.hide().insertAfter(wrapper)
            //    lastCreated = "#" + o["Id"];
            //} else {
            //    sel.hide().insertAfter($(lastCreated))
            //}

            sel.hide()

            wrapper.after(sel)
          }
        })
      };

      function runOrder(id) {
        var obj;
        if ($('#' + id).is('[class*="cTrig_"]')) {
          obj = $('#' + id).attr("class").split("cTrig_")[1]
          $('#' + id).after($('#' + obj))

          runOrder(obj);
        }
      };

      initialized();
    });
  };

}(jQuery));



$('#cDropdown').cDropdown({
  obj: [{
    "year": {
      "Id": "year",
      "Name": "year",
      "Primary": true,
      "Class": "form-control",
      "Child": "Model",
      "Sort": true,
      "Required": true,
      "option": [{
        "val": "CPreQVa",
        "text": "Step 1 - Select Year",
        "preSelect": true
      }, {
        "val": "1990",
        "text": "1990"
      }, {
        "val": "1991",
        "text": "1991"
      }, {
        "val": "1992",
        "text": "1992"
      }]
    },
    "Model": {
      "Id": "Model",
      "Name": "Model",
      "Class": "form-control",
      "Child": "Engine",
      "Sort": true,
      "option": [{
        "val": "CPreQVa",
        "text": "Step 2 - select Model",
        "preSelect": true
      }, {
        "val": "80",
        "text": "80",
        "trigger": "1990"
      }, {
        "val": "80",
        "text": "80",
        "trigger": "1991"
      }, {
        "val": "80",
        "text": "80",
        "trigger": "1992"
      }]
    },
    "Engine": {
      "Id": "Engine",
      "Name": "Engine",
      "Class": "form-control",
      "Sort": true,
      "option": [{
        "val": "CPreQVa",
        "text": "Step 3 - Select Engine",
        "preSelect": true
      }, {
        "val": "v10",
        "text": "v10",
        "trigger": "80"
      }]
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cDropdown"></select>
```

Comment: Thank You, that's amazing but i still need to send the selected values to email, how can i do that also? I'm sorry if i sound "stupid" but i'm new to coding